# FragmentTransaction call from another fragment makes activity variables null

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, fragmenttransaction

The Background is animated with a `ValueAnimator` and a customized `ValueAnimator.Update` method. In activity `onCreate` method, with `FragmentTransaction`first fragment calls. And from the first fragment, another `FragmetTranstaction` called based on user button click. On the first transaction everything works perfect but in the second one, the activity variables that used in `ValueAnimator.Update` goes null. Where is the problem?

Activity `onCreate`:

```
    private const int TO_LEFT = 0;
    private const int TO_RIGHT = 1;
    private const long DURATION = 15000;

    private int bgAnimDir = TO_LEFT;
    private RectF mDisplayRect = new RectF();
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private ValueAnimator bgAnimator;

    [BindView(Resource.Id.background)]
    ImageView background;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Cheeseknife.Bind(this);

        background.Post(() =>
        {
            animate();
        });


        fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.home_container, new Home(), "Home");
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
```

The null pointer exception raised for both background and matrix variables

`animate()` function:

```
    private void animate()
    {
        updateDisplayRect();
        if (bgAnimDir == TO_LEFT)
            animate(mDisplayRect.Left, mDisplayRect.Left - (mDisplayRect.Right - background.Width));
        else
            animate(mDisplayRect.Left, 0.0f);
    }

    private void animate(float from, float to)
    {
        bgAnimator = ValueAnimator.OfFloat(from, to);
        bgAnimator.Update +=
            (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) =>
            {
                float value = (float)e.Animation.AnimatedValue;
                matrix.Reset();
                matrix.PostTranslate(value, 0);
                background.ImageMatrix = matrix;
            };
        bgAnimator.SetDuration(DURATION);
        bgAnimator.AnimationEnd +=
            (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                bgAnimDir = bgAnimDir == TO_LEFT ? TO_RIGHT : TO_LEFT;
                animate();
            };
        bgAnimator.Start();
    }
```

Exceptions raised in `bgAnimator.Update` delegate

Comment: You want to show animation in inactive fragment and that's why you having this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using try , catch.

Here is my new animate function:

```
    private void animate(float from, float to)
    {
        bgAnimator = ValueAnimator.OfFloat(from, to);
        bgAnimator.Update +=
            (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    float value = (float)e.Animation.AnimatedValue;
                    matrix.Reset();
                    matrix.PostTranslate(value, 0);
                    background.ImageMatrix = matrix;
                }
                catch
                {
                    background = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.background);
                }
            };
        bgAnimator.SetDuration(DURATION);
        bgAnimator.AnimationEnd +=
            (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                bgAnimDir = bgAnimDir == TO_LEFT ? TO_RIGHT : TO_LEFT;
                animate();
            };
        bgAnimator.Start();
    }

    private void updateDisplayRect()
    {
        try
        {
            mDisplayRect.Set(0, 0, background.Drawable.IntrinsicWidth, background.Drawable.IntrinsicHeight);
            matrix.MapRect(mDisplayRect);
        }
        catch
        {
            background = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.background);
        }
    }
```

Just fill the null variable when its need to be!

But as you can guess, this is not a briefly answer to explain why the background goes null in the process!.